# Как избавиться от подергиваний текста для textarea с автоматической высотой?

Tags: vue.js

Делаю авто расширяющийся textarea.

Принцип такой: создаю скрытый div, в который помещается вводимый текст и по updated() определяется высота div'а и применяется к текстовому полю.

Но есть одна проблема - видно подергивание текста, т.к. на долю секунды текст уползает вверх, а потом при расширении поля - возвращается на свое место. Как будто updated() срабатывает с опозданием.
По такому же принципу делал текстовое поле в реакте, такого эффекта не было.

Что можно с этим поделать?

```js
var VTextArea = Vue.component('VTextArea',{
  template : '#v-text-area',
  props: {
      autoRow: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      default: String
    },
    data : function(){
      return {
        value: this.default,
      }
    },
    mounted: function(){   
      this.updateHeight()
    },
    updated: function(){
      this.updateHeight()
    },
    methods: {
      updateHeight: function(){
        
          this.$refs.textarea.style.height = this.$refs.shadow.clientHeight + 5 + 'px'; 
      }
    }
});

new Vue({
el : '#app',

components: {VTextArea: VTextArea},
methods : {

},
computed : {

},
ready : function(){

}

});
```

```css
.textarea_wrap {
    position: relative;
  }

  .textarea {
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 12px; 
  
  }

  .shadow {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    resize: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <v-text-area :auto-row="true"></v-text-area>
 
</div>

<template id="v-text-area">
 <div class="textarea_wrap">
    <textarea class="text_input textarea" v-model="value" ref="textarea"></textarea>
    <div v-if="autoRow" class="text_input textarea shadow" ref="shadow">{{ value }}!</div>
  </div>
</template>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать в принципе без js - это решает Вашу задачу, если не привязываться к `textarea` (думаю так не получится, браузеры очень строго стилизуют этот элемент), но можно с div `contenteditable`.

```html
<div contenteditable style="
border: 1px solid #ccc;
height: auto;
min-height: 50px;
max-height: 200px;
padding: 20px;
overflow-y: scroll;
">
asd asd asd 
</div>
```

Comment: Это не работает: https://jsfiddle.net/ov024jLt/